# Preload cached images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-category

Using **SDWebImage library** I am caching the images at runtime.What I want is to preload all UICollectionViewCell's images as when i scroll to the end no flicker or placeholder to be visible.Is it possible to preload all the images in the UICollectionViewCell.I tried with **SDWebImagePrefetcher** also.Help Required.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you find solution ? If yes, Please do share it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use AFNetworking's UIImageView+AFNetworking category. It will handle the placeholder etc automatically, and will do everything in a background thread, ensuring that the main thread doesn't get blocked. Specifically, this is the method you'd want to call:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But as I already told that I am using SDWebImage and it is working perfectly.My issue is more with showing the images that are out of the screen.Like reusability of imageView in UICollecitonViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You will have to preload and maintain an `UIImage` cache. You need to predict the images that are going to be shown if user scrolls back or forth from his current position and perform some sane amount preload in both directions in a background thread. Then, in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you should first check it the image is already in your preloaded cache, and if it is there just assign it to you UIImageView.

Also make sure to utilize the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method to get a cell object for configuration

You performance will be best if you make sure that UIImageView bounds will be exactly matching the UIImage dimensions. You can control this at the UIImage creation time by specifying the scale factor, given you know the metadata of your raw image data beforehand.

Comment: Can you please provide me any example.